# Why isn't Android Studio seeing upgraded Java?

Tags: java, android, macos, android-studio

I'm having an issue with Android Studio `1.0.1`. I downloaded and installed it on a MacBook running Yosemite `10.10.1`. When I tried to make a 'Hello World' application, it complained that it requires JDK7 to compile android-21. I had JDK6 installed. So I upgraded Java, and I figured why not just get the newest version and so I installed JDK8. Then, I uninstalled and reinstalled Android Studio and restarted the computer. When I run `java -version`, the terminal tells me that I'm running version 8. However, my directory structure still looks like `/System/Library/Java/JavaVirtualMachines/1.6.0.jdk/...`. Android Studio still doesn't like it and complains that I need JDK7. I tried editing the plist file for Android Studio and changing the JDK to 1.8 from 1.6 and this did not work. That was everything I could find on the internet so far. I was thinking I could uninstall Java and then install JDK7 but I don't have much experience with that as I'm a Linux user and so I'm clueless as to how to do a few things on Mac, like an equivalent of `apt-get uninstall java` in order to actually try this out. Alternatively, I'm not sure what program to drag to the Trash to uninstall. How can I resolve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have `JDK 1.7` installed and make `JAVA_HOME` variable point to the JDK 1.7 directory then Android Studio will find your `JDK 1.7` following your `JAVA_HOME` variable

Comment: I tried changing the `JAVA_HOME` variable in a few places and it finally worked when I went into `Android Studio->Preferences->Path Variables` and added it there. Thanks a lot!